# Performance issue with resolver in angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am creating a Dashboard component of our app which holds 2 child components which also have child components (see image below).

[image]

All of these components have (8) HTTP requests connecting to different endpoints to be able to display appropriate data (statistics) and quite big. Now I am having poor performance issue.

When a user is in the Dashboard and while the contents are loading (Http request ongoing) and decides to move to another component (let's say Users page), all the HTTP requests gets cancelled as seen from the browser's debugging network tab. And the **resolver** (UserResolver which gets the updated user details) http requests comes in with **pending** status.

The problem now is it takes a while for the request to finish and move to the route change. I've checked the backend web server logs, and while the status is pending from the browser, it is not reflected yet to the logs.

My assumption here is, Angular does not fire up the http request for the resolver immediately "on route change". If it's immediate, then I should be seeing from the web server logs right?

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1:-

While calling multiple API`s need to use **forkJoin** RXJS method.
for example:-

```
let userData = this.userService.getUserList();
let analyticsData = this.analyticService.getUserAnalyticsData();
...
...

forkJoin([userData, analyticsData]).subscribe(res =>{
this.userDatas = res[0];
this.analyticsDatas = res[1];
}
```

Answer 2:-

You have to subscribe API call at once by using **forkJoin** method.

Comment: If that's the case, then I should be calling all the http requests to the main component and pass down to children. I'll have to look at this. Thanks!